# How to parametrize instance id in AWS CloudWatch template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to configure a dashboard with CPUUtilization metrics. We have 12 instances and every week we spin down these instances and our Cloudwatch dashboard becomes obsolete without those underlying instances. 
Next time when we spin up new set of servers, we have to manually go to dashboard and edit it with the new instance IDs
This is manual process and we need to automate it.
I attached the basic template that we use for current dashboard.

```
{
"widgets": [
    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 9,
        "height": 9,
        "properties": {
            "view": "timeSeries",
            "stacked": false,
            "metrics": [
                [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "i-0894e335e6ad2e561", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-01fde0cee726e7896", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-096e96499aa827924", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-0e550d881bcbf41c5", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-041a59616f061a373", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-06a6237975ec0f274", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-052f844dd071eab25", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-02dfa8d807c1f5477", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-0cda118fc6e375093", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-02ef6dfd642f2ffd4", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-0e0e9c12d672a48a7", { "period": 60 } ],
                [ "...", "i-0eb432b4098c4e9d8", { "period": 60 } ]
            ],
            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "period": 300,
            "title": "TEST CPU Utilization",

        }
    }

]
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a cloudwatch event triggered on new running instances

[image]

You define a lambda function as target and in it, you can make the [PutDashboard api call](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_dashboard):

```
client.put_dashboard(DashboardName='string', DashboardBody='string')
```

The cloudwatch event will tell you which instance ID it has been triggered and you can use that in the mentioned api call.

You can also listen on terminate event and have the instance automatically removed from the dashboard.

Finally, make sure your code runs for exactly the instances you intended to. I suggest you use a tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by generating the CloudFormation in question, specifically, using a templating language and a bash script to bootstrap the templating.

> [Templating in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)
>
> [Templating in Java](https://freemarker.apache.org/)
>
> [Templating in Javascript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Depending on the syntax of your chosen templating language, I expect your template file would look something like this:

```
...more cloudformation...
{
"widgets": [
    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 9,
        "height": 9,
        "properties": {
            "view": "timeSeries",
            "stacked": false,
            "metrics": [
                <% for instance in instances { %>
                    [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "<% instance.id %>", { "period": 60 } ],
                <% } %> 
            ],
            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "period": 300,
            "title": "TEST CPU Utilization",
        }
    }

]
}
... more cloudformation...
```

Once you have a templating process identified, you will need to be able to find your instance id's, so that they can be fed to the templating process as input.  For that I recommend using EC2 Tag's to give identifying tags to your instances, and use the AWS CLI to query for such instances.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:[tagName],Values=[tagValue]"
```

This command should be run from the same script mentioned above, with the output fed to the templating engine.

**Note that the [tagName] and [tagValue] should be replaced with your own tagName and tagValue that you provided to your instances as mentioned above.**